# Good starting points for blackberry widget development

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

Which good resources for starting widget development for blackberry do you have?

Are there any tutorials that go further then a hello world? Advices on how to structure your app how to integrate second party java-script libraries something like this?

Sadly the rim documentation is nearly non existent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent blog with advanced concepts and tutorials:

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/

And this site has a wonderful tutorial on creating a blackberry game that describes and exemplifies complex layout issues.

http://www.toniwestbrook.com/archives/69

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great tutorials on RIM Widget API:

http://mobijournal.com/using-invoke-apis-in-your-blackberry-widget/

http://mobijournal.com/blackberry-sqlite-tutorial/

http://mobijournal.com/common-blackberry-webworks-development-pitfalls-that-can-be-avoided/